# Teamcity build log prints one or several symbols per each line

Tags: teamcity

Teamcity build log prints one or several symbols per each line.

I get the following output while build is running:

[image: build log output - 1]

[image: build log output - 2]

It is quite hard to read such output. Is there any way to force Teamcity print log for the entire length of the lines?

UPDATE: Our team found out that build log was affected by maven-surfire-plugin which was added to pom.xml. As we don't need this plugin for our current needs it was enough to remove it for resolving the problem.

Comment: There was a bug in anchient versions of TeamCity which can manifest like this, but it is long fixed. If you are on a recent version, it is worth reporting to JetBrains (via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW) with some steps to reproduce and describing what kind of environment it is on the agent (OS, hardware, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Yaegor for your reply. Our team found out that build log was affected by maven-surfire-plugin which was added to pom.xml. As we don't need this plugin for our current needs it was enough to remove it for resolving the problem.